# Connecting 2 ubuntu machines as a LAN

Tags: networking, lan

Hi i am trying to connect 2 ubuntu computers as a LAN.

In my current setup I have:

One machine running ubuntu 11.10 with Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller

While the other machine is running Ubuntu 12.04 with an Atheros Communications Inc AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet

The two machines are connected via a switch (Edimax ES-3205P).

Unfortunately I still cannot connect the two machines together. Can somebody please show me what to do and how to go about solving this issue?

Thank you

ANSWERED

All I had to do was set up both ip's maually, subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 and left blank both gateway and DNS.

Comment: A brief explanation about what you did to achieve the connection may be proved useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the IPs manually using the 'network connection' GUI to, say, `192.168.1.1` on ubuntu 11.04 machine and `192.168.1.2` on ubuntu 12.04 machine. Set the netmask to `255.255.255.0` on both of them. Leave the dns and gateway fields blank (I am assuming you only want each other to talk with no internet). This will work. If you wish to connect just these 2 machines, then there is no need of a switch - directly connect each other with the ethernet cable.
(I assume you know how to create a new connection in ubuntu and set the ip manually.)

Comment: +1. Can you see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/151515/61218) about doing the same thing on a virtual machine

Comment: Is there a guide - step-by-step instructions for a newbie - on how to connect two ubuntu machines over WLAN so that they can share files, etc between themselves and also be able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the IP's on both of them,Ip can be consecutive where as all the other, subnet, gateway and DNS should be same. I think this should work!